Communication with Docker console application from another container
I am developing a web application. The request to the server contains a .tex file that needs to be compiled and the result (.pdf) sent in the response. I have selected tectonic engine to compile the .tex.  It is a small console engine that automatically downloads dependencies.
I want to build a docker compose service. The web application is built by myself in docker image. tectonic engine image I found in docker hub - rekka/tectonic.
Question: how can I call tectonic from another container (web application)?
Probably I can't, since tectonic is unreachable.
I have connected my two containers via volume. this way i can access files from both and for example save the .tex file from request to volume, and then upload from volume the compiled .pdf to response). However, I still haven't figured out how I can access tectonic from web container and call compile that .pdf.
version: '3.8'

services:
  tectonic:
    image: rekka/tectonic
    tty: true
    volumes:
      - tex-volume:/data/
    
  tectonic-rest-serv:
    image: tectonic-rest:latest
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - tex-volume:/var/lib/latex

volumes:
  tex-volume:

I have one idea, perhaps I can run a trigger when creating a container with tectonic that will constantly check to see if a .tex file has appeared in the volume. But this solution doesn't seem to me to be the best option.

Can't you reach the service from localhost:8080?

I can. that's not the point. calling host localhost:8080 -> localhost:8080 mapping to web server in container -> web server in container should call tectonic in another container. how do I call tectonic?

mm yes understood. From container you can't use localhost, you can use 192.168.99.100 (that is the internal docker ip address) ora rather you can use the name of the service.
Try to use [service-name]:8080, let me know!
For Example I configured in a docker-compose a service for the database called postgresdb and a service for pgadmin. To link pgadmin to the database I used the "ip" called postgresdb and as host: docker.host.internal.
So, it should work if you use the service name instead of localhost, when you wnat to communicate between containers.
Let me know if it works

You don't show your image's Dockerfile, but can you install a TeX distribution directly there, and run pdftex as an ordinary subprocess?  You won't be able to invoke this container without having unrestricted root-level access over the entire host and non-portable Docker configuration, and I'd avoid that.

@GiacomoBrunetta TeX is a non-interactive document formatting tool; you'd run for example pdflatex foo.tex and it would produce a foo.pdf as output.  There's no server process to call with a cross-container call.  It predates Docker by multiple decades.

Related: Docker : Can a container A call an executable located on an other container B?, even invokes pdflatex as the target binary.  Its one answer has a couple of options.
